# How to fix: React-Native android / Gradle build fails

Tags: node.js, android-studio, gradle, react-native

I am working on a react-native (android) project using google maps, it was working a few weeks ago but it has stopped working. The Gradle Daemon starts but build fails.

Ive tried the solutions recommended on others posts but they don't work.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=false
```

---

### Gradle 5.0

Build time:   2018-11-26 11:48:43 UTC
Revision:     7fc6e5abf2fc5fe0824aec8a0f5462664dbcd987

Kotlin DSL:   1.0.4
Kotlin:       1.3.10
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_191 (Oracle Corporation 25.191-b12)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-50-generic amd64

---

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    package="com.mapstest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"

      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
      android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
      >
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="AIzaSyCw6zvGM1e1TkbECk8oH8M3cuYKvtyqq1k"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

### build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mapstest"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
}
```

---

### gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m 

VERSION_CODE=4
VERSION_NAME=0.24.2
GROUP=com.airbnb.android

POM_DESCRIPTION=React Native Map view component for Android
POM_URL=https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/tree/new-scv
POM_SCM_URL=https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/tree/new-scv
POM_SCM_CONNECTION=scm:git@github.com:airbnb/react-native-maps.git
POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION=scm:git@github.com:airbnb/react-native-maps.git
POM_LICENSE_NAME=MIT
POM_LICENSE_URL=https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/LICENSE
POM_LICENSE_DIST=repo
POM_DEVELOPER_ID=airbnb
POM_DEVELOPER_NAME=Leland Richardson

POM_NAME=ReactNative Maps library
POM_ARTIFACT_ID=react-native-maps
POM_PACKAGING=aar

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=false
```

The project was compiling but has stopped working, I am receiving the following errors in my terminal.

```
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.1.
Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.graphics.drawable.IconCompatParcelizer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.core.internal.package-info found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.CustomVersionedParcelable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.NonParcelField found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelField found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelImpl$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.ParcelUtils found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel$1 found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcel$ParcelException found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelParcel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream$FieldBuffer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelStream$InputBuffer found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelable found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
  Duplicate class androidx.versionedparcelable.VersionedParcelize found in modules classes.jar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0)
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?